# htaccess redirect double query string

Tags: string, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Due to a coding error I have a bunch of false URLs that need to be rewritten in htaccees.

The query part of the URL got somehow duplicated and must now be stripped down to a single query part, e.g.

http://www.example.com/?abc=def/?abc=def to http://www.example.com/?abc=def

I was hoping to find a solution with wildcards so that it would work whenever a double query string occurs - regardless of the query. However my coding skills are not good enough to do so ...

I hope you can help! :-)

Answer (score -1):

Try :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /\?abc=(.+?)/\?abc= [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /?abc=%1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: @sumurai8 thanks for the information and the downvote, Right now I am busy in a meeting with my clients, I will update the answer after some time.